# Docker run does not binding host port

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to run simplest asp.net core 3.1 WebApplication inside docker as simple as possible but, docker does not binding host port.

**Host:** Windows 10

**Container target:** Linux

**Docker version:** 20.10.7

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication.dll"]
```

Docker build command (ok)

```
docker build -t webapplication .
```

Docker run command (ok)

```
docker run webapplication -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443
```

When I try to access website on my localhost (http://localhost:5000) I'm getting **This site can’t be reached**. Running the `docker ps` returned ports information without host mapping port

[image]

Comment: add `-p` right after `run`

Comment: Your run command should be `docker run -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443 webapplication`

Comment: Thank you! I really thougth that order did not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @marzelin correctly pointed out, you need to add the flag right after run.